# Rails: Upload to Instagram programmatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

I want to upload photos to my own instagram account programmatically from my Rails app. I've only been able to find posts from ~2013 that state this is against Instagram TOS. Is there any update or are photo uploads still disabled using the Instagram API?

Answer (score 1):

Instagram API still doesn't allow upload from any third-party apps. This is their conscious decision and I don't think it will change any time soon.